# React-Router Tabs component mounting before data is fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have come across an issue where I have multiple nested routes to make a tabbed component ideally clicking on the tab will change the url, stay on the page and render a component as children. This works just fine.

The reason for using url routes as tabs is so that if somewhere else in the app a user click `sales/:id/notes` it will go directly to the correct tab.

The issue is that I am fetching all the data from the `componentDidMount` function in the parent route. So when `SalesShowPage` mounts it makes a request. If I go directly to `SalesShowPage` and then click on a `NotesTab` all data is loaded perfectly since it made the request on load.

The issue happens if we go directly to the `sales/:id/notes` because `NotesTab` is a child component its `render` and `componentDidMount`methods gets called before `SalesShowPage` if I try to set an `isFetching` flag in state it wont get called until after the `NotesTab` has mounted because its making the request action from the parent component.

When looping through all the notes  this will throw an undefined error for notes.

Is there a better way of handling the data fetching from the parent of Nested Routes with react-router?

Can I delay the rendering of the routes component or show a loading message when the data is actually fetched from the parent? I don't want to arbitrarily set an isFetching flag from `componentWillMount` and then the data fetches and a fake loading icon is showing.

I could just make request for all the notes when that component mounts but that would require changing the `API` endpoint and adding another route. Instead of using the current end point.

The below code is a simplified version to make it easier to understand.

```
// Routes.js
<Route path="/sales/:id" component={SalesShowPage} >
   <Route path="contacts" component={ContactsTab}/>
   <Route path="notes" component={NotesTab}/>
   <Route path="emails" component={EmailsTab}/>
</Route>
```

The `{props.children}` being rendered below is the component from the above routes.

```
//Tabs.js
const Tabs = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='tabsContainer'>
      <TabsHeader>
          <Link to='sales/:id/contacts'>Contacts</Link>
          <Link to='sales/:id/notes'>Notes</Link>
          <Link to='sales/:id/emails'>Emails</Link>
      </TabsHeader>
      <TabsContent className='tabContent'>
        {props.children}
      </TabsContent>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the main component that gets rendered and fetches the data for all the tabs. Not all tabs have data being fetched on this component load some of the tabs will make there own request for data. Such as the emails tab which wont query all the emails on initial page load because of the query size and how often that tab is viewed.

```
//SaleShowPage

class SalesShowPage extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchSales(this.props.saleId);
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className={styles.flex}>
            <SalesDetails sale={this.props.sale}/>
            <Tabs {...this.props}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    saleId: props.params.id,
    sale: state.sales[props.params.id],
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchSale: (id) => dispatch(fetchSale(id))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SalesShowPage);
```

The below action is a replica of the request to the server from SalesShowPage `componentDidMount` method setting the `isFetching` flag to true works. but gets executed after our specified Tab Component has been rendered resulting in errors.

```
//SalesShowAction.js

export function fetchSale (id) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: actions.FETCH_SALE_REQUEST, isFetching: true});
    return API.get(`/sales/${id}`).then( json => dispatch(receiveSale(json)));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're fetching once the component has mounted, which means that it will render out the tabs that you need to fetch data for while you're still getting that data. I'd recommend a two-pronged approach:

First, start fetching that data *before* mounting, in `componentWillMount()`:

```
componentWillMount () {
  this.props.fetchSales(this.props.saleId);
}
```

But because it's an async action, it's still unlikely to finish in time, so you need a fallback:

```
SalesShowPage.defaultProps = {
  showTabs: false
};
```

Then you can render `Tabs` if `showTabs` is `true`, which you can set on the success action for the request.

```
renderTabs() {
  if(this.props.showTabs) {
    return <Tabs {...this.props}/>;
  }
}

render () {
  return (
    <div className={styles.flex}>
          <SalesDetails sale={this.props.sale}/>
          {this.renderTabs()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to hide the whole UI until the tabs are ready, you could use `isFetching` to show a loading screen instead.